# Mouse events are not working in element within button (IE11)

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

all. have strange situation with IE, when element with mouse events within button - events will not trigger. this situation is not reproduce in Chrome or Firefox. unfortunately there is no info about this situation, perhaps someone was has same situation?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<button>BUTTON
<div ng-mouseover="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Mouse over me!</div>
</button>


<h1>{{count}}</h1>

<p>This example will increase the value of the variable "count" every time the mouse cursor moves over the DIV element.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason IE11 isn't seeing you as mousing over the child `<div>`, but instead it sees you mousing over the parent `<button>`.

This can be fixed by moving the `ng-mouseover` attribute to the `<button>` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<button ng-mouseover="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
    BUTTON
    <div>Mouse over me!</div>
</button>

<h1>{{count}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately button has his own events :(
I found one solution - use instead button - div. not clean solution, but...